# Adding Recipients through RestAPI docusign Bug/Not?

Tags: docusignapi

I have been doing this adding recipients through RestAPI since two months but experiencing this issue for about a week now. I request anyone out there, please try to add a recipients through restapi for an in-process envelope by a trigger. My api call in trigger handler looks like

```
public static void functionName(string envelopeId)
 {
    string UserId = 'userId';
    string Password = 'password';
    string AccountId = 'accountId';
    string IntegratorKey = 'Ikey'; 
    string Endpoint = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/';
    String myBody;
    myBody = '{"signers": [{"signInEachLocation": "false","name": "Check1","email": "test@email.com","recipientId": "5","requireIdLookup": "false","routingOrder": "5","roleName": "role1"}, {"signInEachLocation": "false","name": "Check2","email": "email@email.com","recipientId": "6","requireIdLookup": "false","routingOrder": "6","roleName": "role2"}]}';

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(Endpoint +'/accounts/'+AccountId+'/envelopes/'+envelopeId+'/recipients/');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication', '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>'+UserId+'</Username><Password>'+Password+'</Password><IntegratorKey>'+IntegratorKey+'</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>');                             
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');    
    request.setBody(myBody); 

    HttpResponse reqResponse = (new Http()).send(request);
    system.debug(reqResponse.getBody());            
 }
```

Initially, Envelope is being sent for routing orders 1, 3, 4, 7, 10. After it reached at routing order 3, i am calling api to add recipients as per above body. For the firstly added recipientId 5, when the envelope comes to recipientId 5's routing number I am getting 2-email notifications to sign the document at a time (Usually it will only be one). I checked my debug logs, everything looks perfect but I can't figure out the cause of the issue.So Is the fault from my end or from Docusign?

Apologies, If I am wrong anywhere.

**Update**

Okay, so here is what I think of the issue. One email notification is sent when the recipient is created (even the envelope did not reach the routing order of this recipient) and same email is sent again when the envelope reached the routing order. Although the latter was only supposed to happen, why am i getting when the email when the recipient is created also?

Comment: What emails are you getting back and to what address? The senders? The one's defined in each role?

Comment: Email notification for signing the document sent to Email address specified in json body  for the added recipient Id '5' when the routing order comes to number 5...

Comment: So recipient 5 gets 2 emails for Envelope Activation? (click here to sign type emails)?

Comment: Yep. Exactly. My concern is Why is he getting 2 emails instead of one?

Comment: Is the text in the emails identical? Can you post the contents of the email with the View Documents link stripped out, just so I am understanding 100% of the problem?

Comment: Yes, they are totally identical except the security code that comes with email to access the documents.

Comment: hey @AndrewWilson could you look at the question update please......

Comment: hey @sam_s I just ran through the same workflow you described and I'm not getting the behavior you're describing. Could you post your calls so I can compare our testing?

Comment: Do both of the emailed recipients have the same recipientId and userId? I've had problems where I accidentally created two signers who had exactly the same email and name but a different routing order. So each recipient had one tab in one document instead of one recipient having a tag in both documents. It's a silly thing but it's happened to me.

Comment: Nope,only one recipient..Could anyone do from their demo docusign environment like this. Send a envelope with 1,3,5,7 routing orders. when envelope is at 5, add a recipient for routing order 6 through rest api. Just reply, how many emails to sign the document are getting for routing order 6 ?  I'm in big ambiguity to decide what's actually going wrong...